# Drupal Module Add Menu Item To Primary Links?

Tags: php, drupal, menu

Is it possible to add a menu item from within `hook_menu()` directly to the `primary-links` menu instead of `navigation` where they like to reside by default?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Actually, it is possible. One of the optional keys in a hook_menu() implementation is in fact 'menu_name', and its value can be the unique name of a given menu. In your case, 'primary-links'. The Devel module uses that technique to add its items to a custom 'Development' menu.

Also note that versions of Drupal 6 earlier than 6.6 (IIRC) had a bug that made it impossible to *move* a menu item already defined in [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu/6) simply by changing the hook_menu() implementation -- you had to explicitly edit the menu item in the UI to reparent it. Drupal 6.7 and later (again, going by memory) fixed that bug and hook_menu is all that's needed.